# Documentation example code snippets

Tags: feature-request, documentation, stack-snippets, documentation-examples

Why can we not add a code snippet to a documentation example?

I would like to add an example to the [block and inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/3447/block-and-inline-elements#t=201608011710003800184) page that showed an examples of each and how they reacted with each other. I think that the best way to do this is in a code snippet. At least in the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript documentation, examples should be able to include code-snippets.